# OpenCV fails to find chess board corners

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am working with an IR camera and am trying to find out if we have any lens distortion. I am using the example from OpenCV [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) to guide my work. I used a chessboard template from [here](https://markhedleyjones.com/projects/calibration-checkerboard-collection) and attached it to the back of a book. Before taking any images I heated the book/paper and observed that the checkerboard pattern was coming in very clear.

I took ~50 still frames with the chessboard pattern tilted/moved so that every part of the frame contained some part of the pattern. An example of one of my images is below:

[image: example calibration image]

I used the following code which resulted in False for every image. I tried every combination of grid pattern sizes from (5-9, 5-9).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob2 as glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base = 'pathtoimages/'
files = glob.glob(base + '*.png')

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,8), None)

    print (ret)
```

I can't figure out why the algorithm is not finding the corners. Any ideas?

**Edit May 30, 2019:**

Today I took some more images with the camera. I took the photos in a more controlled environment without any external light sources present. These new images still fail the findchessboard corner detection. I tried increasing the contrast and brightness using cv2.convertScaleAbs to produce the following image as an example.

[image: Increased Contrast]

This also fails. If I use cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack to find corners I get the following result:

[image: corners]

It seems like the Opencv corner detection algorithm is actively avoiding my chess board corners. It will find any corner it can before finding one on the chessboard. I am truly stumped here.

As a sanity check I made sure that openCV can find the corners on the original chessboard I am using and it worked perfectly.

Any ideas?

**Edit June 4, 2019:**

I ended up writing a script that allows me to manually assign each of the corners. I was able to get the camera distortion model successfully. I still have no solution for why the corners couldn't automatically be found by openCV. I think if I were to do this again in IR, I would make a custom grid that increases the contrast between grid cells simply due to differing thermal properties between "white" and "black" grid cells (use different materials).

Comment: try to increase the contrast

Comment: I tried a couple of thresholding techniques with no success. I tried doing a binary threshold with an adaptive gaussian method and also binary thresholding using otsu's method. I played with parameters in the guassian method but couldn't really find something that worked really well.

I also tried clipping the data between some min max value to highlight the chess board but again had no luck.

Comment: the contrast here is still way too low.

Comment: > The function requires white space (like a square-thick border, the wider the better) around the board to make the detection more robust in various environments. Otherwise, if there is no border and the background is dark, the outer black squares cannot be segmented properly and so the square grouping and ordering algorithm fails.

Comment: I can see that and will keep that in mind for a future test however, even IF I had that border, clearly openCV corner detection is having a hard time finding the corners in the chess board. Even if I manually black everything out that isn't the chess board, drastically increase the contrast, AND clip the frame to the data range of the chessboard chunks, openCV refuses to find the corners.

Answer (score 3):

I got `findChessboardCorners` to work with 2 adjustments.

1. As said in one of the comments, **openCV** expects a white boarder
   around the chessboard. To achieve that you can 'invert' the image,
   essentially creating the equivalent to a photographic negative.
   Before I called `findChessboardCorners`, I did: `image_inverted = 
   numpy.array(256 – image_original, dtype=uint8)`
2. Only use the `cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THREASH` flag when calling
   `findChessboardCorners`. `CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK` and
   `CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE` flags seem to make `findChessboardCorners`
   not find the corners.

Good Luck

Comment: It should be `255 - image_original`